# Basic batch, wont enter for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, imagemagick

I'm trying to write a simple batch script to use identify (from ImageMagick) to check dimensions of files in this directory and decide its orientation. Later, I'll be adding moving them to seperate folders. 
The problem is it can't enter the for loop.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /r %%F in (*.) do (
    identify -format "%%w" %%F > temp.txt
    set /P temps=<temp.txt
    set /A w=%temps%
    identify -format "%%h" %%F > temp.txt
    set /P temps=<temp.txt
    set /A h=%temps%    
    if /I "%w%" GEQ "%h%" echo Is Landscape
    if /I "%w%" LEQ "%h%" echo Is Vertical
    pause   
)
pause
```

Comment: besides you need [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) inside your `for` loop - how do you know, you "can't enter" it?

Comment: Checked, when I just have nothing but pause inside it wont pause. So nothing inside it isnt executed.

Comment: that should mean, it didn't find any files without extension. Are there any?

Comment: Do you know what the file mask `*.` means? it matches files without extension; to match *all* files, use `*.*` or `*`...

Comment: That was the problem, typos... Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `identify` tell you the width and height in a **single** call for all files in the directory, rather than calling it **twice** for **each and every** file:

```
identify -format "%w %h %f\r\n" *.png

1024 768 a.png
10 10 b.png
```

So, you can pair that up with your script and do it this way faster and more succinctly:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Get dimensions and names of all files in one go
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=+" %%A in ('identify -format "%%w+%%h+%%f\r\n" *.png') DO (
   REM %%A is width, %%B is height, %%C is name
   ECHO %%A,%%B,%%C
)
```